# Bootstrap: How might I keep a dropdown menu open to click within a nested dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

- I've got an `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`
- One of its children `<li>` contains another `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`
- From what I understand, clicking inside `<ul>` toggles the parent `<ul>` to its off-state, closing it, which prevents clicking on a sub-category.

Just need a fix to keep the `<ul>` open until the specific `<li>` in which it is nested is clicked.

---

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO][1]**

---

Thanks

---

UPD: What I was trying to achieve is (was) better accomplished using an accordion.

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, @TheMiniJohn Just updated it.

Comment: I found an implementation of this: http://www.bootply.com/IbeApcjZEW

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle isnt working correctly, but the way to do it is with preventDefault();

```
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You should name classes of the 'ul' tags you want to keep open something like ".stayopen" and use that class in the js function rather than ".dropdown-menu", otherwise all your dropdowns will stay open.

Comment: My `<ul>`'s still close when I click outside of them, I need the to close only when their parent (`<li>`) is clicked.